# How do I create (or update) a QBO BillPayment so that it has an unapplied payment amount?

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I created a bill through the QuickBooks Online (QBO) web UI. Then I queried using the API (v3, documented [here](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/api/accounting)). The response:

```
{
    "SyncToken": "16", 
    "domain": "QBO", 
    "VendorRef": {
        "name": "MyVendor", 
        "value": "237"
    }, 
    "TxnDate": "2014-12-07", 
    "TotalAmt": 1.83, 
    "CurrencyRef": {
        "name": "United States Dollar", 
        "value": "USD"
    }, 
    "PayType": "Check", 
    "PrivateNote": "test billpayment description (mod)", 
    "sparse": false, 
    "Line": [
        {
            "Amount": 1.22, 
            "LinkedTxn": [
                {
                    "TxnId": "1412", 
                    "TxnType": "Bill"
                }
            ]
        }
    ], 
    "Id": "1413", 
    "CheckPayment": {
        "PrintStatus": "NeedToPrint", 
        "BankAccountRef": {
            "name": "MyBankAcct#1234", 
            "value": "137"
        }
    }, 
    "MetaData": {
        "CreateTime": "2014-12-07T18:44:51-08:00", 
        "LastUpdatedTime": "2014-12-10T20:20:28-08:00"
    }
}
```

As you can see, **it has $0.61 of the TotalAmt unapplied to any Bills.** (The other $1.22 is applied to Bill 1412.) Now, *when I try to update this bill to change JUST the amount applied to the linked transaction*, I get unexpected results.

Here's the update request body:

```
{
    "SyncToken": "16", 
    "domain": "QBO", 
    "VendorRef": {
        "name": "MyVendor", 
        "value": "237"
    }, 
    "TxnDate": "2014-12-07", 
    "TotalAmt": 1.83, 
    "CurrencyRef": {
        "name": "United States Dollar", 
        "value": "USD"
    }, 
    "PayType": "Check", 
    "PrivateNote": "test billpayment description (mod)", 
    "sparse": false, 
    "Line": [
        {
            "Amount": 1.21, 
            "LinkedTxn": [
                {
                    "TxnId": "1412", 
                    "TxnType": "Bill"
                }
            ]
        }
    ], 
    "Id": "1413", 
    "CheckPayment": {
        "PrintStatus": "NeedToPrint", 
        "BankAccountRef": {
            "name": "MyBankAcct#1234", 
            "value": "137"
        }
    }, 
    "MetaData": {
        "CreateTime": "2014-12-07T18:44:51-08:00", 
        "LastUpdatedTime": "2014-12-10T20:20:28-08:00"
    }
}
```

In the response, it appears that the API just basically can't handle the situation (even though it clearly existed when I created it in the web UI). **Look what happens to the TotalAmt attribute!** It's reduced to whatever the payment was in the LinkedTxn:

```
{
  "BillPayment": {
    "VendorRef": {
      "value": "237",
      "name": "MyVendor"
    },
    "PayType": "Check",
    "CheckPayment": {
      "BankAccountRef": {
        "value": "137",
        "name": "MyBankAcct#1234"
      },
      "PrintStatus": "NeedToPrint"
    },
    "TotalAmt": 1.21,
    "domain": "QBO",
    "sparse": false,
    "Id": "1413",
    "SyncToken": "17",
    "MetaData": {
      "CreateTime": "2014-12-07T18:44:51-08:00",
      "LastUpdatedTime": "2014-12-10T20:25:02-08:00"
    },
    "TxnDate": "2014-12-07",
    "CurrencyRef": {
      "value": "USD",
      "name": "United States Dollar"
    },
    "PrivateNote": "test billpayment description (mod)",
    "Line": [
      {
        "Amount": 1.21,
        "LinkedTxn": [
          {
            "TxnId": "1412",
            "TxnType": "Bill"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "time": "2014-12-10T20:25:01.91-08:00"
}
```

I don't see discussion of this on the [known issues page](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0100_accounting/0600_more/qbo_v3_known_issues), so I'm pretty confused.

If you have any suggestions as to how to get this to do what I want it to, I thank you for your thoughts!

Comment: As u mentioned, it seems API can't handle this. It looks like a bug.